# Unity Fog effects the main floor

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, game-development

I looked for ways to create a simple fog effect in unity and see that it is already a built-in feature in lightning. I setup the fog settings as below:

[image]

It worked for the objects far away but also affected the floor (the floor has completely different texture normally):

[image]

How can I fix it like excluding the floor from fog or should I place my floor underneath the player and move it with the player(that d be sad for me) ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/ignore-fog-on-specific-object.201116/), you can define a secondary camera to render objects you don't want to render fog. Next (based on [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnPreRender.html)), you can write a code to enable/disable fog for each camera:

```
    private bool revertFogState = false;

    void OnPreRender()
    {
        revertFogState = RenderSettings.fog;
        RenderSettings.fog = enabled;
    }

    void OnPostRender()
    {
        RenderSettings.fog = revertFogState;
    }
```